# How to copy picture in same position for all slides

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint, microsoft-powerpoint-2007

I have made my presentation which is about 60 slides long and I want to copy a logo to the same position of each slide. Is there a way to do this without manually copying and pasting the logo? I am using powerpoint 2007.

Answer (score 4):

View tab, Presentation Views, select Slide Master.

This is a master slide and master slides for each slide type. Select the larger slide at the top and add your image and it will appear on all slide types. To have it only appear on some edit each type's master.

When done select the Slide Master tab and to the far right Close Master View.